# how to select rows from lists in r?

Tags: r, list

```
df1 = data.frame(
y1 = c(1, -2, 3),
y2 = c(4, 5, 6),out = c("*", "*", "")
 )
```

## Create another dataframe

```
  df2 = data.frame(
   y1 = c(7, -3, 9),
   y2 = c(1, 4, 6),out = c("", "*", "")
   )
```

## Create list of data frame using list()

```
   lis = list(df1, df2)
```

I want to compare row by row (first row from index [[1]] with first row from index [[2]]  and so on

if both rows have * or empty (similar) under out, then select the row with the highest absolute value in y1 (and put under ind the index)

otherwise, take the y1 value of the row with * under out (and put under ind the index)

example of desired output:

```
 y1 y2 out ind
 1  4   *    1
-3  4   *    2
 9  6        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to bind the dataset with `bind_rows` and specify `.id` to create an identifier for the `list` sequence.  Then grouped by the `rowid` of the 'ind' column, either we `arrange` the rows in the group so that `*` values in `out` will be first, then do the order on absolute values of 'y1' in `desc`ending.  We `slice` the row with the `max` absolute value in 'y1' if the number of distinct elements in 'out' is 1 or else return the 1st row (will be `*` in out if there is one)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
bind_rows(lis, .id = 'ind') %>% 
  group_by(rn = rowid(ind)) %>%
  arrange(out != "*", desc(abs(y1)), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(if(n_distinct(out) == 1) which.max(abs(y1)) else 1) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(y1, y2, out, ind)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     y1    y2 out   ind  
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1     4 "*"   1    
2    -3     4 "*"   2    
3     9     6 ""    2
```

---

Or without `arrange`, after grouping, create a position index in `slice` ('i1') where the values in out are `*`, then use that index to subset the y1 values to find the position where it is absolute max in `else` case and return the position of 'i1' by indexing

```
bind_rows(lis, .id = 'ind') %>% 
  group_by(rn = rowid(ind)) %>%
  slice({i1 <- which(out == "*")
   if(n_distinct(out) == 1) which.max(abs(y1)) else 
      i1[which.max(abs(y1[i1]))]}) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(y1, y2, out, ind)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     y1    y2 out   ind  
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1     4 "*"   1    
2    -3     4 "*"   2    
3     9     6 ""    2
```

---

Or use a similar ordering approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 dt1 <- rbindlist(lis, idcol = "ind")[, rn := rowid(ind)]
dt2 <- dt1[order(rn, out != "*", desc(abs(y1)))]
dt2[dt2[, .I[if(uniqueN(out) == 1) which.max(abs(y1)) else 
      1L], .(rn)]$V1][, rn := NULL][]
   ind y1 y2 out
1:   1  1  4   *
2:   2 -3  4   *
3:   2  9  6
```